# Installing Ubuntu with the Windows installer

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, wubi

After installation of Ubuntu 12.10, during restart the Boot menu does not appear. Computer automatically loads Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

If you used WUBI to install within Windows then Ubuntu is is used as a Program not as a true dual-boot. Please consult [this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) which may help resolve your issue.